# Is blender the best modelling tool to use with Three.js?

Tags: three.js, html5-canvas, blender

I started working on HTML5 canvas last year. Soon I wanted to experiment with it in 3D. I came across Three.js (http://threejs.org) and I started having fun with it.

When I came across some other examples on the web that use Three.js I realized that there was a way to actually create very realistic objects to use in Three.js and after a search I came across blender (http://www.blender.org).

So far it has been a blast! It allows one to model virtually anything very easily.

But now I am beginning to wounder whether there might be another modelling tool out there that anyone here has come across that easily export into an "js" file that can be imported into Three.js.

The reason I ask is because I want to weigh my options so as to not be heavily dependent on one model tool if others are out there.

Thanks

Comment: That's a matter of opinion and budget. For price you can't beat blender. If you know and can afford other 3d apps then you may prefer to use them.

Comment: It's opinion based, but personally I prefer Lightwave. Many prefer 3D Max and there is Maya and a bunch of others incl. Blender. There are specialized software such as Poser/Daz 3D (humans, Daz 3D is free but you need to buy most of the content as with Poser) but these are not directly a modelling tool per-se, and Vue for landscapes. All these can export Wavefront OBJ and Collada which you can convert into "js".